# Making a booktabs table

Tags: booktabs

I don't really know how to make tables with `booktabs` and other posts on this don't seem to help me too much.

I have to make a table similar to the one with the image below. How would I get on with something like this? 
[image]

Comment: It would help if, in addition to saying which parts you don't know, you explained which parts you know how to do already. This is best demonstrated through the addition of some basic code in the form of an MWE. But: Do you know how to make a `longtable`? What about the coloured rows? (The `booktabs` 'parts' here look to me like `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation using also `siunitx`. You should adjust the settings for `table-format` according to the real data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\captionsetup{font=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{Processed Data}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{white}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{3}{% fix here the values
   S[table-format=1.0]
   S[table-format=1.0]
   S[table-format=1.0]
  }
}
\toprule
\rowcolor{white}
{\splitcell{Number of sheets of \\ Dielectric Material}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Dry Paper (C)/\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Waxed Paper (C)/\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Impregnated Paper (C)/\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
\rowcolor{white}
& {Average} & {\splitcell{Standard \\ Deviation}} & {\splitcell{Absolute \\ Uncertainty}}
& {Average} & {\splitcell{Standard \\ Deviation}} & {\splitcell{Absolute \\ Uncertainty}}
& {Average} & {\splitcell{Standard \\ Deviation}} & {\splitcell{Absolute \\ Uncertainty}} \\
\midrule
 8 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
16 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
24 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
32 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
40 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
48 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
56 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
64 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
72 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
80 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
88 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
96 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think that the stripes are good, though, so I also add the “stripe free” version (removing `\rowcolors` and `\rowcolor` commands).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wiki for LaTeX/Tables is a great resource: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

To create the above table you need to combine a few different packages for tables. Below is a small working example that you should be able to expand to cover your case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\begin{varwidth}{#1}\centering}c<{\end{varwidth}}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\colorlet{rowColorBase}{white}
\colorlet{rowColorAlternate}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Table 1: Processed Data}
\rowcolors{1}{rowColorAlternate}{rowColorBase}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {@{}M{3.1cm}*{3}{xxx}@{}}
    % Table header, repeated at every page
    \toprule
    Number of sheets of Dielectric Material & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dry Paper (C)\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Waxed Paper (C)\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Impregnated Paper (C)\si{pF} \SI{\pm 0.01}{\percent}}  \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{rowColorBase} & Average & Standard Deviation & Absolute Uncertainty & Average & Standard Deviation & Absolute Uncertainty & Average & Standard Deviation & Absolute Uncertainty\\
    \endhead
    % Table footer, repeated at every page except last
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{Table continues on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    % Final table footer on last page
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
    \endlastfoot
    % Table content
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
     8 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    16 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    24 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    32 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
    40 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    48 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    56 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    64 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
    72 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    80 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    88 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    96 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The resulting table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You should use the `\specialrule` command to eliminate the white strips below `\midrule`s (they use custom values for `\aboveryulesep` and `\belowrulesep`.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the example. I have also incorporated the nice add-ons of @egreg